# Each elements of list of strings to be split

Tags: python, string, pandas, loops, split

I just carried out pandas series object, which looks like followings:

```
0        ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', ...]
1        ['str5', 'str6', 'str7', 'str8', ...]
2        ['str9', 'str10', 'abcde.fghi', 'str12', ...]
.
.
.
```

Here, I'd like to keep the format, and split the strings like 'abcde.fghi' with delimiter '.'

1. Replace "abcde.fghi" with  "abcde"
2. Insert "fghi" after "abcde" followed by "str12"

It needs to stay in that format. What I want is the following:

```
2        ['str9', 'str10', 'abcde', 'fghi', 'str12', ...]
```

The series of lists is not just them. It's like 300000 lines of them, so I need the split function in the iteration.

+++
I got this series after I applied nltk word_tokenize.

```
lists_above=mydataframe['textcolum'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

But, as the data have many sentences without whitespace, so I'm trying more steps

Comment: `[x for item in ['str9', 'str10', 'abcde.fghi', 'str12'] for x in item.split('.') ]`

Comment: Probably look at using apply in pandas with the function @futas just provided

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with a lambda list comprehension in pandas pretty easily:

```
df['words'] = df['words'].apply(lambda x: [item for sub in x for item in sub.split('.')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( first one if your list is a string, 2nd if your list is a list):

```
df['yourcolumn'].apply(lambda x: "', '".join(x.split('.'))) 

or

df['yourcolumn'].apply(lambda x:  eval("', '".join(str(x).split('.'))))
```

output:

```
0       ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str4']
1       ['str5', 'str6', 'str7', 'str8', 'str1']
2    ['str9', 'str10', 'abcde', 'fghi', 'str12']
```

Comment: I think this only works assuming the rows are strings not a list...i.e. if each row (x) is a list, you can't split a list

Comment: @DerekEden  my dataframes usually print without quotes when its a list: 0              [str1, str2, str3, str4, str4]
1    ['str5', 'str6', 'str7', 'str8', 'str1']

Comment: @DerekEden sometimes it's confusing to know, i just went with the output, but i'll add an update as the other, especially if Jay P would like to see

Comment: I hear you..I think they just typed the lists manually with the quotes..in the OP they say "series of lists" so lead me to believe they were a list of strings